# How do i replace a specific element in a JavaScript array without knowing the index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi ive looked at similar questions but they weren't helpful.

I am creating a guestlist that takes 10 people, if the user tries to add an 11th name to the array, the program should say, “You have already added 10 people to your guest list. Would you like to replace someone on the list with this person? y/n: ”

If the user enters “y”, the program should output the current guest list and then
asks, “Who would you like to replace?”

this is my code:

```
let i = 0;
let input = names;
do {
   
   input = names.push(prompt("Who would you like to invite to your dinner party?"));

 i++;
}
while (names.length < 11);

if (names.length == 11 ){
   input2 = prompt(`You have already added 10 people to your guest list. Would you like to
   replace someone on the list with this person? Y/N:`)
}

let yes = "Y";
let no = "N";

if (input2 === yes){
   replaceInput = prompt((`Your guests are:${names}
  
  Who would you like to replace?`));
} 

alert(`your new guests are: ${names}`)
```

now how do i make the program replace the person the user specifies with the 11th
person given and output the updated list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the index of selected guest and replace the guest on that index with the 11th guest. Check the example code for more clarification:

```js
// inputs
let currentNames = ["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"]

// this variable will have the result of the first prompt() call (new guest)
let newName = "X11";

// this variable will have the result of the second prompt() call (guest to replace the new guest with)
let nameToReplace = "X5";

// implementation
let indexOfNameToReplace = currentNames.indexOf(nameToReplace);
if (indexOfNameToReplace > -1) {
  currentNames[indexOfNameToReplace] = newName;
  console.log(`New array is: ${currentNames}`);
  // New array is: [X1,X2,X3,X4,X11,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10]
} else {
  console.log(`No guest found by the given name: "${nameToReplace}"`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in an array.

By using the indexOf(), we are finding the index of the name the user inputs (replaceInput) and replacing it with the (newInput), as long as the index value is not -1.

```js
let names = [];
let i = 0;
let input = names;
do {
  input = names.push(
    prompt("Who would you like to invite to your dinner party?")
  );

  i++;
} while (names.length < 11);

if (names.length == 11) {
  input2 = prompt(`You have already added 10 people to your guest list. Would you like to
   replace someone on the list with this person? Y/N:`);
}

let yes = "Y";
let no = "N";

if (input2 === yes) {
  replaceInput = prompt(`Your guests are:${names}
  
  Who would you like to replace?`);
  newInput = prompt("Enter New guest name: ");

  const nameReplace = names.indexOf(replaceInput);

  if (nameReplace !== -1) {
    names[nameReplace] = newInput;
  }
}

alert(`your new guests are: ${names}`);
```

Comment: As `names` is an array, `names[replaceInput]` won't do anything usefull. You will need to find the correct index first ...

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use `push()` method in javascript arrays. For example:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Arrays</h1>
<h2>The push() Method</h2>

<p>push() adds new items to the end of an array:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const fruits = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
fruits.push("5", "6");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when you run this code the result will be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```